# Sony WH-1000XM4 Pipewire microphone forces the switch to mSBC

Tags: arch-linux, bluetooth, bluez, pipewire

I recently purchased some headphones Sony WH-1000XM4. I have also switched from pulse to pipewire mostly for bluetooth auto-connect.
I managed to connect them, but I have several issues (1 where LDAC,AptX HD and AptX are not an option) even though I would like to figure out how to enable any of the newer codecs, I can live without them (AAC is good enough).

But my biggest problem is that when I use my microphone it forces everything to mSBC (headphones as well).

list sink returns:

```
State: RUNNING
Name: bluez_output.F8_4E_17_2E_BC_6A.a2dp-sink
Description: WH-1000XM4
Driver: PipeWire
Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Owner Module: 4294967295
Mute: no
Volume: front-left: 30446 /  46% / -19,98 dB,   front-right: 30446 /  46% / -19,98 dB
        balance 0,00
Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
Monitor Source: bluez_output.F8_4E_17_2E_BC_6A.a2dp-sink.monitor
Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
Flags: HARDWARE HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
Properties:
    api.bluez5.transport = ""
    api.bluez5.profile = "a2dp-sink"
    api.bluez5.codec = "aac"
    api.bluez5.address = "F8:4E:17:2E:BC:6A"
    device.routes = "1"
    card.profile.device = "1"
    device.form_factor = "headset"
    device.bus = "bluetooth"
    device.id = "49"
    device.description = "WH-1000XM4"
    node.name = "bluez_output.F8_4E_17_2E_BC_6A.a2dp-sink"
    factory.name = "api.bluez5.a2dp.sink"
    priority.driver = "1010"
    priority.session = "1010"
    device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
    node.pause-on-idle = "false"
    factory.id = "8"
    device.api = "bluez5"
    media.class = "Audio/Sink"
    node.driver = "true"
    node.latency = "512/48000"
    factory.mode = "merge"
    audio.adapt.follower = ""
    library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
    object.id = "113"
    object.serial = "3480"
    client.id = "31"
Ports:
    headset-output: Headset (type: Headset, priority: 0, available)
Active Port: headset-output
Formats:
    pcm
```

I'm using pipewire 1.0.3.43-1, bluez 5.63-1, libldac 2.0.2.3-1 Archlinux with kernel 5.15.13.arch1-1

Answer (score 2):

AAC/LDAC/APTX (high quality audio codec) cannot used for 2 way communication (mic and high quality audio).
if you want to use the headphone for call (mic on), you must sacrifice the audio quality. also it happen with almost all audio bluetooth devices.
with that reason, bluetooth codec wil be forced into mSBC or CVSD